# Can we self-generate a client out of a Rest controller using annotation processing ? If we can then how I can proceed?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, java-annotations, annotation-processor

(https://github.com/aashrai/brahma-dao), similar to this DAO generator can we do annotation processing to generate a client for a rest controller ?

**PS : I am using Spring Boot with gradle.**

Comment: For a JVM client I assume? Or Android perhaps?

Comment: Basically, I want this for Spring boot with gradle. @ColinAlworth

Answer (score 3):

[Domino-rest](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-rest) can do that, it generates a client from a jax-rs interface resource.

the generated client works in JVM, and will automatically map JSON responses/requests.

a short sample can look like this

the jax-rs interface

```java
@RequestFactory
public interface MoviesService {

    @Path("library/movies/:movieName")
    @GET
    Movie getMovieByName(String movieName);

    @Path("library/movies")
    @GET
    List<Movie> listMovies();

    @Path("library/movies/:name")
    @PUT
    void updateMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie);
}
```

and the generated client can be used like this

```java
MoviesServiceFactory.INSTANCE
    .getMovieByName("hulk")
    .onSuccess(movie -> {
        //do something on success
    })
    .onFailed(failedResponse -> {
        //do something on error
    })
    .send();
```

there is lots of supported features and enough documentation to get you started.

> please note that this is still under development and is still in SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Can we do it in SpringBoot with gradle ?

Comment: Yes you can, but the code generation is based on JAX-RS annotation not spring mapping.